# Transport from Copenhagen bus station to the cruise ship port

Tags: copenhagen

How can I get from Copenhagen to the cruise port to embark the NCL cruise liner?

I will be travelling from Hamburg, Germany with Flixbus.

Comment: https://www.visitcopenhagen.com/cruisecopenhagen/copenhagen/transportation-and-cruise-terminals

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk +1 for doing the research; make that into an answer and I'll upvote.

Answer (score 1):

Copenhagen doesn't really have a bus station, (most of) the long distance buses terminate at the central station (for trains), but actually in two different places.

[Visit Copenhagen](https://www.visitcopenhagen.com/cruisecopenhagen/copenhagen/transportation-and-cruise-terminals) has a page with a lot of information on going to the cruise port, you'll probably want bus 26.